# Prototype Multi select with search box

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am looking for prototype multi select just like jquery . My project is on only prototype. 
So If i get similer javascript it will help . Here I am Attached one image for example.

[image: I want similar selector]

Comment: Take a look at Chosen - its not exactly the same as your screenshot but take a look http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/index.proto.html

Comment: Its very close . thank you for the reply .. But still if I want to select quickly I have to open again select and select one more time. Thats time consuming . But its helpfull. Thank you